# How to iterate a list inside a list in java?

Tags: java, list, arraylist, iterator

Hi i have two value object classes .

```
package org.array;

import java.util.List;



public class Father {

    private String name;
    private int age ;
    private List<Children> Childrens;
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }
    public void setAge(int age) {
        this.age = age;
    }
    public List<Children> getChildrens() {
        return Childrens;
    }
    public void setChildrens(List<Children> childrens) {
        Childrens = childrens;
    }


}
```

second is for children

```
package org.array;

public class Children {

    private String name;
    private int age ;
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }
    public void setAge(int age) {
        this.age = age;
    }


}
```

and i want to print there value i nested a list inside a list here i am putting only a single value inside the objects while in real i have many values . so i am nesting list of children inside father list. how can i print or get the value of child and father both. here is my logic.

```
package org.array;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;

public class ArrayDemo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
         List <Father> fatherList = new ArrayList<Father>();
        Father father =  new Father();
        father.setName("john");
        father.setAge(25);
        fatherList.add(father);

         List <Children> childrens = new ArrayList<Children>();
         Children children = new Children();
        children.setName("david");
        children.setAge(2);
        childrens.add(children);
        father.setChildrens(childrens);
        fatherList.add(father);

        Iterator<Father> iterator = fatherList.iterator();
        while (iterator.hasNext()) {
            System.out.println(iterator.toString());
        }



        }
        }
```

Comment: Just as a note, you appear to be adding `father` to the `fatherList` twice. I'm not sure if that was intentional. This is outside the scope of the question, but might cause you confusion later on.

Comment: you are correct marc thanks for your advice

Comment: @user2142786 use foreach loop instead of Iterator bcoz iterator are little bit slow

Answer (score 4):

You can use a nested `for` loop to accomplish this. Here's an example:

```
for (Father f : fatherlist) {
    System.out.println("Father: " + f.getName());
    System.out.println("Children:");
    for (Children c : f.getChildrens()) {
        System.out.println(c.getName());
    }
}
```

Using the `Iterator` approach, you would accomplish it this way:

```
Iterator<Father> i = fatherList.iterator();
while (i.hasNext()) {
    Father f = i.next();
    System.out.println("Father: " + f.getName());
    System.out.println("Children:");
    Iterator<Children> ci = f.getChildrens().iterator();
    while (ci.hasNext()) {
        Children c = ci.next();
        System.out.println(c.getName());
    }
}
```

As a general style suggestion, I would suggest renaming the `Children` class to `Child` and rename the methods `getChildrens` and `setChildrens` in `Father` to `getChildren` and `setChildren` respectively.

I would even suggest taking it a step further and remove the `setChildren` method and provide an `addChild(Child child)` method such that you have control over the `List` that contains the children. A benefit to this is that you can guarantee a `List` is instantiated such that these loops you are defining won't hit a `NullPointerException` in the case that no children were added to a particular `Father` instance.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `advance forloop` for iterating (which is equals to using `iterator`) child ArrayList and parent ArrayList

**sample:**

```
 for(Father  f : fatherList)
 {
    for(Children c : f.getChildrens)
    {

    }
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Iterator<Father> iterator = fatherList.iterator();
        while (iterator.hasNext()) {
           Father father = iterator.next();
              Iterator<Children> childiter = father.getChildren().iterator();
              while(childiter.hasNext()){
                  System.out.println(childiter.next().toString());
               }

        }
```

Comment: Hi it has to be getChildrens.iterator()

Comment: Hi, that is not grammatically correct. Id suggest changing your function name

Answer (score 1):

Override toString() in Father and Children. Your toString() implementation of Father should use children.toString() to build the resultant string and that is it. Then printing the father will print the details of father and children both.

Children implementation of toString()

```
public String toString() {
StringBuffer buff = new StringBuffer();
    buff.append("[Name : ");
    buff.append(this.name).append(", Age : ");
    buff.append(this.age);
    buff.append("]");
    return buff.toString();
}
```

Father implementation of toString()

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    StringBuffer buff = new StringBuffer();
    buff.append("[ Father Name : ");
    buff.append(this.name);
    buff.append(", Age : ");
    buff.append(this.age);
    buff.append(", Childrens : { ");
    for (Children children : getChildrens()) {
        buff.append(children);
        buff.append(" ");
    }
    buff.append("}");
    return buff.toString();
}
```

Then printing Father will print the information about Father and Children both.

```
System.out.println(father);
```

Comment: Can you please define in detail

Comment: I'm a little anal about this, but `toString` should never be overridden simply to provide "display" data, that's what a formatter is for, instead, `toString` should be used to provide useful information about the state of the object which can be, especially, for debugging - but that's just me...

Comment: @jdphenix - you are right but it is not allowing me to add new comment since I have a very less reputation.

Comment: @MadProgrammer Ohhh... I just realized what this answer is saying after reading it again.

Comment: @MadProgrammer - Right but POJO classes like these doesn't maintain any state. The intention here is to avoid the overhead of nested looping.

Comment: Of course they maintain state, how many fathers/children objects do you think you can create :P. As I said, this is just my (anal) opinion ;)

Answer (score 1):

Just to print the objects, you may use below code snippet

```
       for (Father father2 : fatherList) {
            System.out.print("Father: "+ReflectionToStringBuilder.toString(father2));
            for (Children children2 : childrens) {
                System.out.print(" Children: " + ReflectionToStringBuilder.toString(children2));
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple use two for loops

```
for (Father f : fatherlist) {
    for (Children c : f.getChildrens) {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Iterating over List using Java 8 forEach.

```
{
            List<Father> fatherList = new ArrayList<Father>();
            // Create Father Object
            Father father = new Father();
            father.setName("john");
            father.setAge(25);
            List<Children> childrens = new ArrayList<Children>();
            // Create child object
            Children children = new Children();
            children.setName("david");
            children.setAge(2);
            childrens.add(children);
            father.setChildrens(childrens);
            fatherList.add(father);
            fatherList.forEach(f -> {
                System.out.println("Father's Name : " + f.getName());
                f.getChildrens().forEach(c -> {
                    System.out.println("Children's Name : " + c.getName());
                });
            });
        }
```