# Looping through Object of Objects in java

Tags: java, loops, iteration

I have an object which in turn contains other objects. Now I have to iterate through this main object and then pick each object and then iterate through them to find out whether any empty fields are present in them. If the object itself is empty, I have to cut it out of main object. Any thoughts on this please.

```
public class Transactions {

private Integer totalTransactionCount = null;
private List<Transaction> transactionsList = new ArrayList<Transaction>();

}

public class Transaction {

private String amount = null;
private Foreign foreign = null;
} 

public class Foreign {

private String amount = null;
private String commissionAmount = null;
private String exchangeRate = null;
}
```

Now I have a Transaction object with me and I have to loop throught each of its fields and in turn loop through their fields to find out any null/empty fields.

Comment: That is very basic programming, you should read some tutorials.

Comment: Please provide sample code

Comment: also this requierement sounds quite confusing. Can you be more specific about your task?

Comment: Please add you code

Comment: It may help if you explain what objects, the way you describe it, it could mean anything, Object is the top of the Class Heirarchy, but what is the parent Object? a List? Set? Array? What is the sub Object? User? Book? CourseItem?

Answer (score 2):

pseudo code for looping through a list of lists:

```
for each (innerList in outerList) do
    if(innerlist.size == 0) then
        //Code for removing empty inner lists.
    else
        for each ( object in innerList) do
            //Check if objects are empty as well and remove it
        end for
    end if
end for
```

**EDIT:** Pointing out lack of research.
I would like to point out that you haven't really done your research properly, simply by googling `iterate list of object` as well as `iterate list of list of object` I got plenty of solutions.
Not to mention a question already asked here on Stack Overflow, please read the [first answer of this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25440465/2136815)